# how to display different div for every 2 seconds?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need div to be display one by one for every 2 seconds from beginning. when one div is display the remaining div should not be displayed

Here is fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jRmrp/71/

**html**

```
<div>
<div id="box1" style="background-color:#0000FF">
 <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>

<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

 <div id="box2" style="background-color:red">
 <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

<div id="box3" style="background-color:green">
 <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

 <div id="box4" style="background-color:yellow">
 <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
 </div>

<div id="box5" style="background-color:orange">
 <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

help me out in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setInterval` :

http://jsfiddle.net/9fqd3p8o/

```js
var id = -1;
$('#container').children().hide();
$('#box1').show();
setInterval(function(){
    id = ++id % 5;
    console.log(id);
    $('#container').children().hide(); 
    $('#box' + (id + 1)).show(); 
},2000)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<div id="box1" style="background-color:#0000FF">
     <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>

    <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>
<div id="box2" style="background-color:red">
     <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
    <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>
<div id="box3" style="background-color:green">
     <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
    <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>
<div id="box4" style="background-color:yellow">
     <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
    <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>
<div id="box5" style="background-color:orange">
     <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
    <p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setInterval()`, try my example below

```js
var id = 1;
setInterval(function () {
  $('#box'+id).hide();
  id++;
  if (id > 5) {
    id = 1;
  }
  $('#box'+id).fadeIn(200);
  
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div id="box1" style="background-color:#0000FF;">
 <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>

<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

 <div id="box2" style="background-color:red; display: none;">
 <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

<div id="box3" style="background-color:green; display: none;">
 <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

 <div id="box4" style="background-color:yellow; display: none;">
 <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
 </div>

<div id="box5" style="background-color:orange; display: none;">
 <h3>This is a heading in a div element</h3>
<p>This is some text in a div element.</p>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take class in every div and write below code:-

```
var currentIndex = 0;
$(".box:not(:eq("+ currentIndex +"))").hide();

var totalDiv = $(".box").length;

setInterval(function(){
     currentIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % totalDiv;

    $(".box").hide();
     $(".box").eq(currentIndex).show();

},2000);
```

Demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/jRmrp/72/